# Facebook Graph API to search user statuses

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to pull some of my facebook statuses that contain a particular keyword and show them on a web page, what is the url query string I should use?

The best I can came up with is graph.facebook.com/me/statuses

But it returns all the statuses, but i want statuses that contain a particular keyword, such in a search, how should I do it? Or is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to manually go through the statuses returned from `/me/statuses` to find the ones that you care about. Facebook doesn't really let you use their computing power to search stuff like that.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but is it a fact, or just an educated guess? Because I've done it with the Twitter API, and don't see why Facebook couldn't do the same.

Comment: Twitter's API is built on the context of tweets, which are text based. Facebook isn't based around that same concept. Facebook has a [Search API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/) but it only retreives public statuses, and you don't get to pick the user from which they come from. If you look at the [Status FQL Table Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/status) you'll see that only the `status_id` and `uid` fields are indexed, which means those are the only 2 columns that are available for filtering via that FQL table.