# Full text search against Facebook statuses using Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Say my app needs to offer a full text search service against all status messages a user posted on Facebook.
So my app will connect to Facebook on the behalf of the user (using OAuth) and use the Graph API to query the statuses.

What I have managed to do so far is:

- using plain Graph API: `/me/statuses`
  List statuses, but there is no way to search against the message (the text inside the status)
- using FQL: `select message from status where uid = me() and strpos(lower(message), 'prague') >=0`
  Search against status messages for a specific keyword ('prague')

The fact that it is not possible to perform an advanced textual search against the status messages has already been discussed in some questions, e.g.: [Facebook Graph API to search user statuses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603533/facebook-graph-api-to-search-user-statuses)

So, in order to provide such a service my app should:

- read all the statuses in: `/me/statuses`
- extract the messages and send them to a full text search engine (like Solr)

Is this the only solution? Do you see a better solution?

Comment: I don't understand, any problem if you do FQL https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=select%20message%20from%20status%20where%20uid%20%3D%20me()%20and%20lower(message)%3D'prague' ?

Comment: I need full text search not just keyword search.
In short, full text search is what search engines (like Google, Solr, ...) do so that if you search for "ski" you get results containing ski, skis, skiing, skiied and so on.
Some web services like Google Drive, Gmail, Twitter offer full text search in their API so f.i. it is possible to perform a full text search against all the documents stored in Google Drive or the twitts in Twitter.